# How to divide a geographic area into N latitude and longitude quadrants

Tags: python, coordinate-system, interpolation

I would like to get the NW1,NW2,...NWn and SE1,SE2,...,SEn lat and long coordinates of N quadrants starting from an area identified by  2 geographic points: NW and SE.

[image]

I would like to write a Python procedure, but I don't know how to calculate the NW1..,SE1.. starting from the boundaries (NW and SE)

Can someone explain me how to get these intermediate latitudes and longitudes?

Comment: Well, it's either trivial, or nearly impossible.  It depends on your definition of "quadrant".  Cartesian quartering will not result in equal-area sections. Even applying a geodesic function to approximate cutting the areas into even chunks is going to result in spheroidal trapezoids, not "quarters".

Comment: I do not need rectangular quadrants, spheroidal trapezoids are ok, and I'm fine with an approximation too. But how can I get these couple of coordinates to divide the area?

Comment: What geometry library are you using, or is this just a math exercise in Python?

Comment: Your picture has seven divisions N-S and six divisions E-W, so it isn't quarter-quarter-quartered. No matter how you quarter (geodesic or Cartesian), you need to find the center,center of the X and Y planes (for Cartesian, this is simple midpoint (`(max+min)*0.5`); for geodesic, you start with a split in the Y dimension, measure the trapezoidal area of the half-panel, divide that in two, apply the Cartesian split in the X dimension, then calculate the trapezoidal area for at the first split point, compare to the goal, adjust the point and try again; Repeat until "close enough".)

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the distance between those data points.

Since you divide into N squares, each square has the same side length, denoted as s.
For one side, if you divide 7 times, you would have 7s.
For the other side, if you divide 8 times, it would be 8s.

As you have the distance between those two points, let's call it d.
By applying the Pythagorean theorem, you would obtain the result for 's', which is the value of the side length for each step

(8s)^2 + (7s)^2 = d^2